# Change Update attribute dynamicaly in Primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces, facelets

I am looking for a way to change the update attribute of a primefaces command button from the backing bean after the form submit. What i am trying to achieve is to update the component id's based on the results from backing bean method.

For example, i am trying to update the form and the growl message with a command button, now if some error has happened from the backing bean(not validation error), i need to update only the growl message and the form shouldn't be updated.

```
<p:commandButton value="Finish Editing"
        action="#{editBean.finish}" icon="ui-icon-check"
        style="width:200px;margin-left:60px;" update=":studentEditForm   :messageForm:applyMessages" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the programmatic API via [`RequestContext#update()`](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/3.5/org/primefaces/context/RequestContext.html#update%28java.lang.String%29).

```
public void finish() {
    // ...

    if (someCondition) {
         RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("someClientId");
    } else {
         RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("otherClientId");
    }
}
```

Don't forget to remove the `update` attribute from the command button.

Answer (score -1):

Change this

```
<p:commandButton value="Finish Editing"
        action="#{editBean.finish}" icon="ui-icon-check"
        style="width:200px;margin-left:60px;" update=":studentEditForm   :messageForm:applyMessages" />
```

to

```
<p:commandButton value="Finish Editing"
        action="#{editBean.finish}" icon="ui-icon-check"
        style="width:200px;margin-left:60px;" update="#{editBean.updateString}" />
```

Now you will have to update this string in EditBean class as required.

Comment: Hello Makky,   It didnt worked, whatever the variable initialized when the form loads it will retain that value for the update argument. Even though i tried to change that string from the backing bean when the form submits, it never reflected in the commandButton 'update' attribute.

Comment: Downvoters care to comment. Some people on SO are just out of their mind.

Comment: Thanks. BalusC . But because you know all the stuff doesn't mean everyone would know. I know you are a GURU but we are not. We are trying to give as close as possible answer. By the way you didn't ask the question. If the asker would do it thne would be fine. If you didn't like my answer then you answer yourself but stop downvoting others..

Comment: I don't care about my reputation. It wont earn me money. I am an average programmer and try to help new programmers so don't expect my posts to be yours post level.